# Custom delete ui-icon casts shadow or margin on some browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a custom icon to close a dialog.  I have removed margins and shadows that surround the button.  However, it still appears on my Android 2.3 device.  It appears correctly (with no shadow) on my Android 4.0 and iOS devices.

I have tried using a png with a transparent background as well as one with a white background to match the dialog's background, but they both give me the shadow.

html:

```
<div class="custom_close_button">
    <a href="#"  data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" >
        <img src="img/close_button.png"></img>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.ui-shadow
{
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
    shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
.custom_close_button
{
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
        padding-right: 20px;
}
.custom_close_button .ui-btn-corner-all
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
    -webkit-border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
    border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
}

.ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    -webkit-border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    border-radius:    0    /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
}
```

Is there a separate setting for Android 2.3 that is causing this?  Below is a screenshot of the button appearing incorrectly on the Android 2.3 device.

Thanks.

[image: Custom Delete Button with some shadow surrounding it]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to use firebug or other developer console and see if the anchor or the surrounding element have the class .ui-icon-shadow applied to it.

The only way I am aware of removing the auto-generated class is via JS/jQuery:

```
 $(".ui-icon-shadow").removeClass('ui-icon-shadow');
```

or via CSS:

```
a.ui-shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Maybe there are other methods via the API...

Comment: Neither of those seemed to work for me. In my case I have an image inside a button (an icon)... what's weird is that when I browse the elements in my browser any shadow CSS rules I see have 'false' beside them...